# Create a tab delimited string from a list of object

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of objects call Person I would like to create a tab delimited string from the list

Example:

```
public class Person 
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
}



List<Person> persons = new List<Persons>();

persons.add ( new person {"bob",15,"999-999-0000"} )
persons.add ( new person {"sue",25,"999-999-0000"} )
persons.add ( new person {"larry",75,"999-999-0000"} )
```

I would like to output that list to a string that would look like this:

```
"bob\t15\t999-999-0000\r\nsue\t25\999-999-0000\r\nlarry\t75\999-999-0000\r\n"
```

right now I was just going to loop through the list and do it line by line the old fashion way.. I was wondering if the was a short cut in LINQ.

Comment: I think the better way is to override your Person ToString method and then use String.Join('\r', list.Select(person => person.ToString()).ToArray()) ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can Use [Strig.Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0.aspx)

```
string str = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, person.Select(r=> r.FirstName +@"\t" +
                                    r.Age + @"\t" +
                                    r.Phone"))
```

Comment: The best one except the "\r" that is not a new line on windows

Comment: @ViacheslavSmityukh, yes I think its better to use `Environment.NewLine`

Answer (score 6):

Aggregate formatted person strings with [StringBuilder](http://www.dotnetperls.com/stringbuilder). Thus you will avoid creating lot of strings in memory:

```
var result = persons.Aggregate(
    new StringBuilder(),
    (sb, p) => sb.AppendFormat("{0}\t{1}\t{2}\r\n", p.FirstName, p.Age, p.Phone),
    sb => sb.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
persons.ForEach(q => output+=(q.firstname+"\\"+q.Age.ToString()+"\\"+q.Phone+"\\"));
```